# What are the controller ids in a Steam announcement?

Tags: steam, controllers

In the Steam announcement "[v1.55 Released - XInput Support, Xbox One Controller Compatibility](https://steamcommunity.com/app/204630/discussions/0/458607699620019523/)", a number of controllers were listed, each with an id of some sort after them. Some of them were as follows:

```
• PS3 dual shock [0x00050925]
• Afterglow PS3 Controller [0x08361A34]
• USB Joystick (PS2 adapter) [0x00030E8F]
• Twin USB Joystick (PS2 adapter) [0x00010810]
• PS2 USB [0x00030810]
• OUYA Controller [0x00012836]
• RetroUSB RetroPad [0x0003F000]
```

What are these ids following the name of each controller? Do they mean something? Is there a list of them somewhere?

Comment: Most likely the hardware ID's for the particular controllers

Comment: The announcement talks about making DirectInput controllers compatible with Xinput and mentions "42 pre-mapped controllers."  I din't count, but I assume that's the list you've quoted part of.  The values after each controller would be the "mappings" (although I'm not sure what that value represents.)

Answer (score 2):

USB and Bluetooth devices are identified by a pair of 16-bit values representing the Vendor and Product. Usually this is what the system will look at when deciding whether a device is supported by a particular driver.

Vendor IDs must be registered with the [USB Implementers Forum](http://www.usb.org/developers/vendor/) to make sure no two devices have the same ID. It's the responsibility of the vendor to assign unique product IDs. A single vendor ID costs $5000.

The hex values in the Steam compatibility notes are 32-bit values with the product ID in the first 4 digits and vendor ID in last 4 digits. The names are a little confusing because none of these devices are genuine Sony gamepads, even when it says PS2 or PS3. There are sites that [maintain lists of known device IDs](https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/), but they are incomplete and sometimes inaccurate.

Let's run through the list to illustrate some of the issues.

**PS3 dual shock** has vendor 0925, registered to [Lakeview Research](https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/0925). A device with that product ID is also known as "Gamtec.,Ltd SmartJoy PLUS Adapter". Probably it's [this thing](https://www.google.com/search?q=SmartJoy%20PLUS&tbm=isch).

**Afterglow PS3 Controller** has vendor 1a34, registered to [ACRUX](https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/1a34). It's not in the database but there's an [open-source project](https://github.com/FIX94/Nintendont/blob/master/controllerconfigs/controller_PDP_Afterglow_AP_1_Controller_for_PS3.ini) that has a configuration file for this gamepad and calls it "PDP Afterglow AP.1 Controller for PS3". Maybe it's [one of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=PDP%20Afterglow%20AP.1%20Controller%20for%20PS3&tbm=isch)?

**USB Joystick (PS2 adapter)** has vendor 0e8f, registered to [GreenAsia](https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/0e8f). Maybe this is the [MaxFire Blaze2](https://www.google.com/search?q=maxfire%20blaze2&tbm=isch)? Or maybe this product ID was reused for a PS2 adapter, as the name suggests.

**Twin USB Joystick (PS2 adapter)** and **PS2 USB** both have vendor 0810, registered to [Personal Communication Systems](https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/0810). The latter is in the database as "PlayStation Gamepad", but I'd be surprised if it is using that trademark with permission.

**OUYA Controller** has vendor ID 2836, which as far as I know was never registered. This is the official gamepad for the now-defunct Android-based [OUYA console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouya).

**RetroUSB RetroPad** has vendor ID f000, which is not registered. Probably it's [this NES-styled gamepad](https://www.retrousb.com/product_info.php?cPath=21&products_id=32&osCsid=144d635acf04df28a8d334c45eed4044).

For gamepads, the most complete sources of information on vendor and product IDs are third-party open source gamepad drivers like [SDL2](https://github.com/gabomdq/SDL_GameControllerDB/blob/master/gamecontrollerdb.txt), [360Controller](https://github.com/360Controller/360Controller/blob/master/360Controller/Info.plist), and [xpad](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/input/joystick/xpad.c#L128).